# How to remove image from starting of wordpress blog post?

Tags: posts

When I am selecting feature image for any post of my wordpress blog then unexpectedly a full width image is whowing starting the blog post. If I removing the feature image only then the image is deleting. I am not finding any option that I can turn off the image from starting of the post.
Can you suggest me the solution of this problem?
To check out the problem live please take a look here:
https://bn.iteachhealth.com/blog/(Simple View)
https://bn.iteachhealth.com/why-children-cry-explained/
Thanks.

Comment: The answer will depend on your theme. You will need to ask your theme’s author for assistance.

Comment: Hello, welcome to WordPress Development.  This is a theme specific question by the sounds of it. Your best bet would be to ask the theme developer. To get an answer here, you will need to add more specific details but you may still be directed to the theme developer as no one will ever know how ALL the themes work. I hope this helps.